# Objective-C Animating a character

Tags: ios

For starters I am trying to animate my main character of the game so I can later replace the images in the array with sprites -

Ive done this in my header file for my main character :

```
- (void)Animate;
```

And in my implementation file ive written :

```
-(void) Animate{

    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle.png"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle02.png"];
    UIImage* img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle03.png"];
    UIImage* img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle04.png"];

    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1,img2,img3,img4, nil];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 160.0)];
    //images.name = @"animation";

    [imageView setAnimationImages:images];
    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    [imageView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    //imageView.center = character.center ;
    [imageView startAnimating];

    // character used to be myView
    // the images inside the array !
}
```

Take note I am using the game feature of Xcode .

So what am I not doing and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You need to add your imageView to, for instance, a view controllers view that is currently displayed so you can see it. Now you allocate a imageview that will just be released when the method returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle"];
UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle02"];
UIImage* img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle03"];
UIImage* img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle04"];


NSArray *animateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1,img2,img3,img4, nil];

self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 160)];

self.imageView.animationImages = animateArray;

self.imageView.animationDuration = 3.0;

[self.imageView startAnimating];

self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;   

[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Comment: thank you so much i understand this code but its saying I need to declare img1,img2 e.t.c also do I replace this code with the code I provided before hand ( I will change it of course )

Comment: oh dw the only issue I have is establishing the imageView as a property

Comment: @TheIOSTroubledProgrammer Yeah you need to declare img1, 2, 3 , just like what you had done. One more point, you dont need to add `.png` while png can be automatically identify. But 'jpg' etc else, you need to add it as suffix.

Comment: Establishing the property is just like `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView` in your header file. And instantiating it in your .m file.

Comment: One final issue I have is the final line where it says :[self.view addSubview:self.imageView]; ive declared the imageview and thats line but when i replace the word View with character (the SKNode ) it gives me an error . Im not sure what to do ?

Comment: What do you want with SKNode? `self.view` is exactly what you see in you screen, which you could add subView in front of it.

Comment: where i have : [self.view addSubview:self.imageView]; it gives me an error where it says self.view , what am i not doing ?

Comment: are you typing the code in a subclass of `UIViewController` ?

Comment: No im not its in the character file